# Aiming to process output data from spacy/rebel pipeline into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spacy

I am trying to process data from output of the rebel component of Spacy pipeline into Neo4j.

Unfortunately Neo4j does not get the syntax of the output data of the pipeline. See the underneath data for the output format.

```
{'relation': 'located in the administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Gràcia, 
'tail_span': Barcelona}
{'relation': 'country', 'head_span': Gràcia, 'tail_span': Spain}
{'relation': 'contains administrative territorial entity', 'head_span': Barcelona, 
'tail_span': Gràcia}
{'relation': 'country', 'head_span': Barcelona, 'tail_span': Spain}
```

The output data should be in this format:

```
  [{'head': 'Gràcia',
    'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Barcelona'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Spain'},
  {'head': 'Barcelona',
    'type': 'contains administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Gràcia'},
  {'head': 'Barcelona', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Spain'},
  {'head': 'Barcelona',
    'type': 'contains administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Gràcia'},
  {'head': 'Barcelona',
    'type': 'contains administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Gràcia'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia',
    'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Barcelona'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Spain'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia',
    'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Barcelona'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia', 'type': 'country', 'tail': 'Spain'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia',
    'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Barcelona'},
  {'head': 'Gràcia',
    'type': 'located in the administrative territorial entity',
    'tail': 'Spain'}]
```

As can be seen, the output of the 'head_span' needs to be in between '' as well. Is there any method how this can be changed accordingly, or does this needs to be changed in the settings of the pipeline?

The code that I apply to import the data in Neo4j is the following:

```
# Your output
data = [{head...}]

query = """
UNWIND $data AS row
MERGE (h:Entity {id: row.head})
MERGE (t:Entity {id: row.tail})
WITH row, h, t
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(h, toUpper(replace(row.type,' ', 
'_')),
{},
{},
t,
{}
)
YIELD rel
RETURN distinct 'done' AS result;
"""

with driver.session() as session:
result = session.run(query, {'data':data})
```

Comment: please also post your input file. thanks.

Comment: The input file is actually a sentence: "Gràcia is a district of the city of Barcelona, Spain. It comprises the neighborhoods of Vila de Gràcia, Vallcarca i els Penitents, El Coll, La Salut and Camp d'en Grassot i Gràcia Nova. Gràcia is bordered by the districts of Eixample to the south, Sarrià-Sant Gervasi to the west and Horta-Guinardó to the east. A vibrant and diverse enclave of Catalan life, Gràcia was an independent municipality for centuries before being formally annexed by Barcelona in 1897 as a part of the city's expansion." Do you also need the code to process this sentence?

Comment: yes, please help me to help you

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Is it ok if I refer to my other post that I just created? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955160/process-multiple-strings-into-a-pipeline  This link also involves another question, but should provide the code required to process the data. In case that anything is missing, please let me know.